# AppGallery Connect Dynamic Ability library exports incorrect Proguard rules that disables compiler optimizations

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

I am trying out AppGallery Connect Dynamic Ability at the moment. I've found out that current Dynamic Ability library exports incorrect Proguard rules which disables compiler optimization. This causes large app size regression after compilation.

The proguard rule in `com.huawei.hms.dynamicability:1.0.14.301` includes the following Proguard rules:

```
-dontshrink
-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses, EnclosingMethod, Exceptions
```

Is there any Dynamic Ability expert who can explain this? Any workaround to resolve this issue? I think the library need to be fixed.

I don't think this is a good idea to export these Proguard rules. It looks like this library is accidentally shipping proguardFile and not consumerProguardFile. Thanks.

Comment: This issue will be optimized in the next version by the end of Jan, 2021. Please follow the [developer support](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-featuredelivery-sdkchangenotes?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: Ok, I will wait for the update then. Thanks.